# Sharepoint 2010 not binding to Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, binding, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I'm trying to get the manager name for a user from the active directory, I created a console program to test it out and everything works fine, when I try the code out in my Sharepoint 2010 program it just gives me the exception "An operations error occurred". 

Upon further debugging I see that it's an error with my principalcontext which throws the exception "In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection." Code is below (note: the code in the try catch is exactly the same as I have it in my console app.):

```
   public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       try 
       {
               // set up domain context
               PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

               // find a user
               UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, Environment.UserName);
               string samAccountName = "";


               if (user != null)
               {
                   // do something here....     
                   samAccountName = user.SamAccountName;
               }


               //Get the manager name from the active directory
               var domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

               using (DirectoryEntry dir = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain))
               {
                   using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(dir, "samAccountName=" + samAccountName))
                   {

                       SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

                       string managerName = result.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
                   }
               }



       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           var message = ex.Message;

       }
   }
```

Comment: Is the ApplicationPoolIdentity running as NetworkService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

to

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAINNAME");
```